# What is the difference between these two ways of obtaining Domain names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, environment-variables

What is the difference between these two statements.

```
    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
```

and

```
    Environment.UserName;
```

Is there any way to retrieve the machine domain without using `System.DirectoryServices`?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname(v=vs.110).aspx

> The UserName property wraps a call to the Windows GetUserName function. The domain account credentials for a user are formatted as the user's domain name, the '\' character, and user name. Use the UserDomainName property to obtain the user's domain name and the UserName property to obtain the user name.

The `Environment.UserName` uses [GetUserName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724432.aspx)

```
Environment.UserDomainName
```

Will get the **User's** domain name.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname(v=vs.110).aspx